# Sum the count within a SQLITE query

Tags: python, sqlite

Within my sqlite query, I'm attempting to not only get the count but also sum the count. This is what I have so far:

```
sql = c.execute("SELECT DISTINCT Org, COUNT(*) AS NUM FROM 2014Data WHERE Action='UPDATED' AND NewValue='' GROUP BY Org ORDER BY NUM DESC")
sql_list = list(sql)
list_count = len(sql_list)
print("2014 Data:")

for i in sql_list:
    print(i)

sql_sum = c.execute("SELECT SUM(NUM) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Org, COUNT(*) AS NUM FROM 2014Data WHERE Action='UPDATED' AND NewValue='')")
sum_list = list(sql_sum)
print("Sum =", sum_list)
print()
```

I get the correct output for the first sql query, but I don't get the correct output for the second.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to get the sum of the table from your first sql statement, then it looks like you just missed adding the group by (GROUP BY Org) you had in the first query.  without having the database and the expected results, below is what I expect will work for you.

```
sql = c.execute("SELECT DISTINCT Org, COUNT(*) AS NUM FROM 2014Data WHERE Action='UPDATED' AND NewValue='' GROUP BY Org ORDER BY NUM DESC")
sql_list = list(sql)
list_count = len(sql_list)
print("2014 Data:")

for i in sql_list:
    print(i)

sql_sum = c.execute("SELECT SUM(NUM) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Org, COUNT(*) AS NUM FROM 2014Data WHERE Action='UPDATED' AND NewValue='' GROUP BY Org )")
sum_list = list(sql_sum)
print("Sum =", sum_list)
```